# Lucene 6 error (cannot instantiate SPI class) in JAR file

Tags: java, apache, maven, lucene, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to run my Java Maven project in a JAR file. It runs on IntelliJ IDEA 2017, however, when running it via the JAR file it does not run. The following error is shown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Cannot instantiate SPI class: org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene62.Lucene62Codec
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:82)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:51)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:38)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder.<clinit>(Codec.java:47)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.getDefault(Codec.java:143)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:121)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:151)
    at com.hrforecast.skillextraction.LuceneIndexManager.buildLuceneIndex(LuceneIndexManager.java:54)
    at com.hrforecast.skillextraction.SkillExtractionModule.getJobsSearcher(SkillExtractionModule.java:129)
    at com.hrforecast.skillextraction.SkillExtractionModule.run(SkillExtractionModule.java:60)
    at com.hrforecast.skillextraction.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat with name 'Lucene50' does not exist.  You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.
  The current classpath supports the following names: [IDVersion]
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.lookup(NamedSPILoader.java:116)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat.forName(PostingsFormat.java:112)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene62.Lucene62Codec.<init>(Lucene62Codec.java:167)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene62.Lucene62Codec.<init>(Lucene62Codec.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:72)
    ... 10 more
```

I have seen similar problems in the other stackoverflow questions for example [What causes err ' A SPI class of type lucene.codecs.Codec name 'Lucene42'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818169/what-causes-err-a-spi-class-of-type-lucene-codecs-codec-name-lucene42) but this also did not solve my problem.

My pom.xml is below. As you can see I tried also to use [Resource Transformers](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html), but it changed nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

...
<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-queryparser -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.26</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!--<plugin>-->
            <!--<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>3.0</version>-->
            <!--<configuration>-->
                <!--<source>1.6</source>-->
                <!--<target>1.6</target>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
        <!--</plugin>-->
        <!--<plugin>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.9</version>-->
            <!--<configuration>-->
                <!--<downloadSources>true</downloadSources>-->
                <!--<downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
        <!--</plugin>-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com..Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html) and as I was using IntelliJ, the problem lied in how I was creating the JAR file.

Instead of creating it using 'artifacts' Build in IntelliJ, I created the JAR file using the 'mvn' tool in the terminal. Make sure your JAVA_HOME is correctly set. I had to install openjdk8 using apt-get again. In the end, the correct JAR file was created in the target directory.

See [here](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-shade-plugin/) for more details on how to create a JAR file using Maven Shade.

(This solution worked for Lucene 6.6.0, Windows 10 bash).