# The "AbstractMethodError" error occurred while executing the "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl()" constructor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I work with a multi-module gradle project (12 modules). I inherited the project and I need to update the versions of some libraries used in it.

I am trying to switch to using the hibernate-core version 5.4.10.Final. I can’t understand the cause of this error:

```
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 48 more
```

I have:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1 (Community Edition) Build #IC-193.5662.53,
  built on December 18, 2019;
- Runtime version: 11-ea+121 amd64;
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o;
- Linux 4.15.0-74-generic;
- GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep;
- Memory: 1204M;
- Cores: 6.

Registry:

- Non-Bundled Plugins: DBN, Lombook Plugin, OdpsStudio,
  com.jetbrains.ChooseRuntime, marcglasberg.HibernateInspectionsPlugin,
  org.dnltsk.mapfileplugin, org.jetbrains.kotlin

This line of the constructor

```
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)
```

contains instructions for calling the “*integrate*” method of the “**Integrator**” interface.

```
285     for ( Integrator integrator : serviceRegistry.getService( IntegratorService.class ).getIntegrators() ) {
286         integrator.integrate( metadata, this, this.serviceRegistry );
287         integratorObserver.integrators.add( integrator );
288     }
```

These class (**SessionFactoryImpl**) and interface (**Integrator**) are part of the “hibernate-core” module of the “org.hibernate” library. I am trying to upgrade to its version 5.4.10.Final.
At the crash site, the "*integrator*" variable is an instance of the "**HibernateSeearchIntegrator**" class.

The “**HibernateSearchIntegrator**” class is part of the “hibernate-search” module. But the inclusion of this module, depending on the module of my project, does not give anything. The project uses the old version of this module (5.3.0.Final), [which had to be returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59733239/exception-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-an-spi-class-of-type-org-apache).

The dependency tree for the main application module looks like this:

```
...$ gradle sa:dependencies --configuration compile

> Task :sa:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :sa
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation' instead).
+--- project :wrath
|    +--- project :domain
|    |    +--- project :model
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0
|    |    |    +--- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.1.0.Final
|    |    |    |    +--- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.4 -> 1.5.1
|    |    |    \--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4
|    |    |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    |         \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
|    |    +--- project :bora
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0
|    |    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.6
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0
|    |    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:65.1
|    |    +--- com.google.gag:gag:1.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
|    |    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.10.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
|    |    |    \--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.3
|    |    +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.1 -> 2.9.7
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.10.22.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.24.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.24.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.24.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.24.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.24.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.13.22.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.24.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.24.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    +--- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.14.3
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25 (*)
|>>>>|>>>>+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-search:5.3.0.Final <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
|    |    |    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.3.0.Final
|    |    |         +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-engine:5.3.0.Final
|    |    |         |    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.5.Final -> 5.1.0.Final
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final
|    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.4
|    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:4.10.4
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.4
|    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-facet:4.10.4
|    |    |         |    |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.4
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:4.10.4
|    |    |         |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.4.GA -> 3.3.2.Final
|    |    |         \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.10.Final -> 5.4.10.Final
|    |    |              +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final
|    |    |              +--- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2
|    |    |              +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.24.0-GA
|    |    |              +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.2
|    |    |              +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    |    |              +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.1.1.Final
|    |    |              +--- org.jboss:jandex:2.1.1.Final
|    |    |              +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.5.1
|    |    |              +--- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0
|    |    |              +--- org.dom4j:dom4j:2.1.1
|    |    |              +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.1.0.Final (*)
|    |    |              +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1
|    |    |              |    \--- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0
|    |    |              \--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1
|    |    |                   +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1 (*)
|    |    |                   +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.1
|    |    |                   +--- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:3.0.7
|    |    |                   +--- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:1.8
|    |    |                   +--- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:1.2.15
|    |    |                   \--- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.30
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    |    \--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
|    |    \--- uk.com.robust-it:cloning:1.9.12
|    |         \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.0.1
|    +--- project :bora (*)
|    +--- io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final -> 3.3.2.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:3.3.8.Final
|    |    \--- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:3.3.8.Final
|    |         \--- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:3.3.8.Final
|    +--- io.undertow:undertow-servlet:2.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.0.Final (*)
|    |    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec:1.0.0.Final
|    |    \--- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:1.0.2.Final
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-orm:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.10.RELEASE
|    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.10.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.10.RELEASE
|    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- com.vaadin:vaadin:6.8.4
|    +--- javax:javaee-api:8.0.1
|    |    \--- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2
|    |         \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.30 (*)
|    \--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0 -> 2.3.1 (*)
+--- project :dataserver
|    +--- project :domain (*)
|    +--- project :serverside
|    |    +--- project :domain (*)
|    |    +--- project :bora (*)
|    |    +--- ru.leasoft.armspk:ostro-core:2.0.7
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.7.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- ru.leasoft.armspk:ostro-api:2.0.7
|    |    |    +--- ru.leasoft.armspk:ostro-core:2.0.7 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.7.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.7.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.0
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.0 (*)
|    |    +--- ru.leasoft.armspk:ostro-ui:2.0.7
|    |    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.poi:poi:3.12
|    |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9
|    |    +--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.poi:poi:3.12 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.12
|    |    |         \--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0
|    |    |              \--- stax:stax-api:1.0.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:3.2.10.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.18.RELEASE -> 5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- net.sf.dozer:dozer:5.5.1
|    |    |    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.1 -> 1.9.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2.1 -> 3.9
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5 -> 1.7.25 (*)
|    |    +--- net.sf.dozer:dozer-spring:5.5.1
|    |    +--- org.javers:javers-core:5.3.4
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
|    |    |    +--- org.picocontainer:picocontainer:2.15
|    |    |    +--- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:4.4.12
|    |    |    +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0-jre -> 28.2-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.lowagie:itext:4.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.6 -> 5.5.13.1
|    |    +--- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:1.1
|    |    |    \--- net.iharder:base64:2.3.8
|    |    +--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 -> 1.7.30
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.30 (*)
|    +--- project :migrations
|    |    \--- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:3.2.1
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:3.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.10.22.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.30 (*)
+--- project :webserver
|    +--- project :domain (*)
|    +--- project :sloth
|    |    +--- project :model (*)
|    |    +--- project :domain (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.gag:gag:1.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13.1
|    |    +--- com.vaadin:vaadin:6.8.4
|    |    +--- org.vaadin.addons:wizards-for-vaadin:0.4.5
|    |    +--- org.vaadin.addon:confirmdialog:1.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.vaadin:vaadin:6.5.7 -> 6.8.4
|    |    +--- org.vaadin.addons:contextmenu:3.1.0
|    |    +--- org.vaadin.addons:stepper:1.2.0
|    |    +--- org.vaadin.addons:easyuploads:0.5.3
|    |    +--- uk.com.robust-it:cloning:1.9.12 (*)
|    |    +--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2
|    |    +--- org.apache.poi:poi:3.12 (*)
|    |    \--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12 (*)
|    +--- ru.leasoft.orgchart:orgchart:0.0.2
|    +--- ru.leasoft.armspk:jasperfont:1.0.0
|    +--- javax:javaee-api:8.0.1 (*)
|    +--- org.dellroad:dellroad-stuff-vaadin:1.0.420
|    +--- io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.0.Final (*)
|    +--- io.undertow:undertow-servlet:2.0.0.Final (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13.1
|    +--- com.vaadin.addon:vaadin-charts-vaadin6:1.1.9
|    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2 -> 2.8.5
|    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:1.4 -> 2.6
|    +--- org.vaadin.addons:refresher:1.1.1
|    +--- org.vaadin.addons:animator:1.6.6
|    +--- org.vaadin.addons:wizards-for-vaadin:0.4.5
|    +--- org.vaadin.addon:confirmdialog:1.2.1 (*)
|    +--- org.vaadin.addons:contextmenu:3.1.0
|    +--- com.google.gwt.google-apis:gwt-visualization:1.1.2
|    +--- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.5.0
|    |    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0 -> 1.9.4 (*)
|    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:2.1 -> 3.2.2
|    |    +--- commons-digester:commons-digester:2.1
|    |    |    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3 -> 1.9.4 (*)
|    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 -> 1.2
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 -> 1.2
|    |    +--- com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js2 -> 4.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- jfree:jcommon:1.0.15
|    |    +--- jfree:jfreechart:1.0.12
|    |    |    \--- jfree:jcommon:1.0.15
|    |    +--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.02
|    |    +--- eclipse:jdtcore:3.1.0
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.castor:castor:1.2
|    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 -> 1.2
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.1.4 -> 2.6.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.1.4 -> 2.6.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.1.4 -> 2.6.0
|    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.5
|    +--- org.jdom:jdom:2.0.2
|    +--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2
|    +--- org.apache.poi:poi:3.12 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.0
|    |    \--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0 -> 2.6.0 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:3.12
|    |    \--- org.apache.poi:poi:3.12 (*)
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.30 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-orm:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.2.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.4.10.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.10.Final (*)
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.6
|         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.4.10.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.10.Final (*)
|    \--- com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.5.3
|         \--- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:0.2.15
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.4.10.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.10.Final (*)
|    +--- org.dom4j:dom4j:2.1.1
|    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.1.0.Final (*)
|    +--- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2
|    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.2
|    \--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.1.1.Final
+--- javax.el:javax.el-api:3.0.0
+--- com.sun.el:el-ri:1.0
+--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.6.11
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1 -> 1.7.30
+--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.5
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.33
\--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.30 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
...$
```

Here you can see that from the project module there is access to the “hibernate-search” module of the “org.hibernate” library. But for some reason, the implementation of the interface in the “**HibernateSearchIntegrator**” class is not available from the “hibernate-core” module.

**Edition 1.**

I tried unsuccessfully to add the dependency on the hibernate-search module directly to the project modules "sa" and "wrath".

Comment: I guess it's version compatibility issue. When interface has some abstract method but implementation class has no such method. Hard to say which exactly library produces the difference. Check versions in your gradle.

Comment: @StanislavL, there is this method in the implementation class, but for some reason this class is not visible, not accessible from the method call point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @StanislavL for the tip! If you change the version of the used hibernate-search module to "5.4.0. Final", the error disappears. I have not tested newer versions yet.